# Use startActivityForResult() in a non-activity Class in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am inflating a Class(no Activity) in an Activity Class. Now what I want to do is I want to Open Gallery from that non-activity Class for which I need to use "startActivityForResult()" and also Override "onActivityResult()" in the same non-activity Class.

I am not able to do it, though I have found some solutions where I can pass the instance of the Activity Class but it's not working.

Can anybody provide the Working Solution Please.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                String strFileName = "temp.jpg";

                fileCameraImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/PAPERCLIP");
                if (!fileCameraImage.exists()) 
                {
                    fileCameraImage.mkdirs();
                }
                file_paperclip = new File(fileCameraImage, strFileName);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file_paperclip));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Now I need to get back to this non-activity Class after Choosing the Desired Image from the Internal Media. But I am not able to override the "onActivityResult()" in this non-activity Class.

Comment: You'll have to show some code, although a wild guess is, you can try making the constructor for that non-activity class, in which you will pass the context from some parent activity class.

Comment: You can call startActivityForResult using activity instance but there is no way to override onActivityResult into non-activity class. Why you are doing?

Comment: Pankaj_I need to do it as I am Opening a Internal Media through Intent and So I need to get back to that non-activity Class after choosing an Image from the Gallery where I need to Call OnActivityResult() which I am not able to Call right now

Answer (score 4):

You can try using   `((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(yourIntent,code);`

Hope it helps..

Comment: i have question here ? i tried your code but it return me to back my activity not on the class ???

Answer (score 0):

Try in this manner:

```
    public class TestNonActivity{

    Activity activity;

    TestNonActivity(Activity activity){
    this.activity=activity;
    }
    public void startConnection() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String strFileName = "temp.jpg";

        fileCameraImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/PAPERCLIP");
        if (!fileCameraImage.exists()) 
        {
            fileCameraImage.mkdirs();
        }
        file_paperclip = new File(fileCameraImage, strFileName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file_paperclip));
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    } 


}
```

And you can create the TestNonActivity class this way from any activity:

```
TestNonActivity testAct=new TestNonActivity(this);
```

and where you have need call this `testAct.startConnection()`

Comment: @Satyaki_See the Question, I have pasted my Piece of Code.

Comment: Thanks for your post , so this code on your non activity class ?

Comment: @DavidBrown is your non activity class extend any Fragment or anything?